# Optimisation problem involving several variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I was solving an optimisation problem as follows:

Two wires of length 4 are cut in the same way into three pieces, of length $x$, $y$ and $z$; the four $x$ and $y$ pieces are used as the four sides of a rectangle; the two $z$ pieces are bent at the middle and joined at the ends to make a square of side $z/2$.

a. Find the rectangle and square made this way which together have the largest and the smallest total area.
Using the answer, tell what type the critical point is.

b. Confirm the critical point type by using the second derivative test

My question is regarding my approach to solving the problem and my confusion regarding the solution provided.

What I did was first to express the area as a function of $x$ and $y$, and find the critical point which is $(1,1)$.

Following that as I think my function $$ A(x,y) = xy + \frac{(4-x-y)^2}{4}$$
behaves in a quadratic manner I would find that max and minimum at the boundaries of the values of $z$. So that would mean $(1,1)$ is a saddle point. Then I proceeded to confirm using the second derivative test as stated by the question.

However, the solution presented said the problem was to find on $R$ the maximum and minimum of the total area $A(x,y)$ where $R$ is the triangle given by $x \leq 0$, $y \leq 0$, and $x + y \leq 4$.

My question is, what is the thinking that leads somebody to consider such a triangle, and what errors are there in my thought process.

Comment: Of course you meant $x,y\ge 0$. You are correct that the interior critical point $(1,1)$ is a saddle point, so the maximum and minimum must both occur on the boundary of the triangle. So examine those (as single-variable max/min problems) separately.

Comment: I don't understand how you are to  define the triangle though, how do i visualise it

Comment: You had it. The triangle with vertices at $(0,0)$, $(4,0)$, and $(0,4)$.

Comment: Ok, I think it's clearer to me.  Thanks man!